# How to filter a formview using a column in a database but without the complete filter parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using formview to display data from access database, i want to be able to filter the formview using a FileNumber but the issue is that this file numbers are saved in such a way that they contain more records under one file number, so when searching the records should be displayed. but the file numbers are long and might differ in each record but the first characters are always the same, so i want to search using only the first characters. for example fileNo R:TM497.99; 19/14/ac; 219/99, i want to search it as r:tm497.99

below is my code

```
        string fe = "";

        if (startdate != "" && enddate != "" )
        {
            fe = "RenDate >= '" + startdate + "' and RenDate <= '" + enddate+ "'";
        }
        else if (startdate != "" && enddate == "" )
        {
            fe = "RenDate >= '" + startdate+"'";
        }
        else if (startdate == "" && enddate != "" )
        {
            fe = "RenDate <= '" + enddate + "'";
        }
        if (paramm != "")
        {
            fe = "Mark  ='" + paramm + "' OR TMNumber ='"+paramm+ "' OR FileNo ='" + paramm + "' ";

        }
        if (txp!= "")
        {
            fe = "Proprietor ='" + txp + "'";
        }

        if (fil != "")
        {
            fe = "[FileNo] like '%{0}%'";
        }
        markdatas.FilterExpression = fe;

        //rebind GridView1
        markdatas.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: string startdate = datesearch.Text.ToString();
            string enddate = todates.Text.ToString();
            string paramm = txtFind.Text;
            string txp = txtpp.Text;
            string fil = serachbox.Text;

Comment: above is my textboxes